# creating a newenvironment with cite

Tags: environments, citing, parameters

This is my first question here.

I would like to create a new environment, call it "citar", which makes those things :
basic "quote" features, + : open and close french quotes,  get the text in italics.

Up to that, I would like to have place for a \cite command after the closing guillemets, using the parameters of the standard \cite fonctions (I'm using Biblatex, if this is relevant to the question)

So I tried to write :

```
\newenvironment{citar}[2]{\begin{quote} \og \itshape \small}{\fg \end{quote}\cite[#2]{#1}}
```

in the preamble, and

```
\begin{citar}{BROUDIC1999}{46}{bonjour}\end{citar}
```

in the document.

Sadly, it doesn't work. I have "illegal parameter number" warnings.

What could I do ?

Thanks in advance,

Malo

*Edit :
- if you want to create an environment as I was looking for, see egreg's answer.
- if you want to customize already existing environments in csquote's package, see Clemen's
- however, the simplest thing I found was to make it a command rather than an environment, see my last answer.*

Comment: I've also tried with ##1 and ##2, doesn't work either

Comment: You can't use the arguments in the "end part" of an environment directly. You can store them in commands at the begin and use these. Check also the csquotes package, it has a lot of "cite environments", you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `\newenvironment` command doesn't allow parameters in the “end part”.

You can use `xparse` and its `\NewDocumentEnvironment` command that does.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{BROUDIC1999,
 author={X. Broudic},
 title={Whatever},
 journal={Journal},
 date={1999},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{citar}{om}
 {\begin{quote}\begingroup\itshape\small \og\ignorespaces}
 {\fg\par\endgroup\nopagebreak
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\cite{#2}}{\cite[#1]{#2}}%
  \end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{citar}[46]{BROUDIC1999}
bonjour bonjour bonjour bonjour
bonjour bonjour bonjour bonjour
\end{citar}

\begin{citar}{BROUDIC1999}
bonjour bonjour bonjour bonjour
bonjour bonjour bonjour bonjour
\end{citar}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I have changed the syntax to be conformant to the syntax of `\cite`, although you probably want the page number always to appear.

The citation marker is inside `quote` in order to avoid page breaks that are always possible after `quote`.

[image]

Variations are possible.

Comment: Thanks very much, egreg ! As Ulrike Fischer suggested to me, I tried to look in the \blockquote possibilities in the csquotes package. \blockquote doesn't exactly behave like I xould like : is it better to try and configure it, or is the option you've given more suitable ?

Answer (score 3):

Like Ulrike said in a comment you can use `csquotes` block environments. Your attempt looks like `csquotes`' `displaycquotes` environment.

The output of those environments can be customized by redefining the hooks

- `\mkbegdispquote{<punct>}{<cite>}`
- `\mkenddispquote{<punct>}{<cite>}`

This will however affect all displayquote environments of `csquotes` (those mentioned in sections 6.1 and 6.2 in the manual). When redefined they should keep two mandatory arguments. Their default definition is equivalent to

```
\newcommand\mkbegdispquote[2]{}
\newcommand\mkenddispquote[2]{#1#2}
```

So something like the following could be what you want:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{BROUDIC1999,
 author={X. Broudic},
 title={Whatever},
 journal={Journal},
 date={1999},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand\mkbegdispquote[2]{\begingroup\small\itshape\og}
\renewcommand\mkenddispquote[2]{\fg\par\endgroup\nopagebreak#1#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaycquote}[46]{BROUDIC1999}
bonjour bonjour bonjour bonjour
bonjour bonjour bonjour bonjour
\end{displaycquote}

\begin{displaycquote}{BROUDIC1999}
bonjour bonjour bonjour bonjour
bonjour bonjour bonjour bonjour
\end{displaycquote}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The result looks the same as in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226892/).

Comment: Similar things can be done for the `\blockquote` macro by redefining `\mkblockquote` (see p.18 of the manual)

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks very much to **egreg** and **clemens**, I've tried your solutions and they work, now I would like to go further, and have two possible ways :

1. **Keeping customizing my environment**

I've modified the original "**citar**" environment given by egreg to add also the single spacing in the quotation (I'm using **setspace** with a 1.5 default spacing), and also add the "cite" informations on the right. So I have :

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{q}{om}
 {\begin{quote}\begingroup\begin{singlespace}\itshape\smaller \og\ignorespaces}
 {\fg\end{singlespace}\endgroup\nopagebreak
 \begin{flushright}
 \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\cite{#2}}{\cite[#1]{#2}}%
 \end{flushright}
  \end{quote}}
```

(I have taken off the "\par", because I didn't know what it was for, and it worked well without it, and renamed "citar" in "q" to be shorter).

It works fine in plain text and footnotes, except that the "cite" informations are a bit low. Maybe because the **singlespace** environment ends before them. But if I try to put the **singlespace** environment elsewhere, I get some problems. It didn't work neither with the **\singlespacing** before \itshape.

2. **Personalizing "displaycquote"**

I've tried Clemen's proposition and tried to add the singlespacing also. It doesn't work with :

```
\renewcommand\mkbegdispquote[2]{\singlespacing\begingroup\smaller\itshape\og}
\renewcommand\mkenddispquote[2]{\fg\endgroup\nopagebreak#1#2}
```

With :

```
\renewcommand\mkbegdispquote[2]{\begingroup\begin{singlespace}\smaller\itshape\og}
\renewcommand\mkenddispquote[2]{\fg\end{singlespace}\endgroup\nopagebreak#1#2}
```

It works fine, except that the **\cite** informations now get on a new line, under the block, while they were at the end of the quotation line, witouhout the singlespace environment.

3. environment or command ?

What I like with **csquotes** is the writing **\enquote{}** is shorter than beginning and ending an environment. I am wondering wether it is possible or not to make something which is writer like :

```
q[46]{BROUDIC1999}{bonjour bonjour}
```

rather than :

```
\begin{q}[46]{BROUDIC1999}
bonjour bonjour
\end{q}
```

I suppose this is not an environment anymore, but a command : the problem is that, if I'm trying to make a command, I don't have brackets for something before it (like \og )and something after it (like \fg), as an environment has.

So command would be better, because shorter, but I don't see how I could write it.

Anyway, thanks for the answers you've already given, I'm getting closer to my goals thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that it was much easier with a **command** than with an environment !

So now I have :

```
\newcommand{\kota}[3]{\emph{\enquote{#3}} (\cite[#1]{#2})}

\newcommand{\kotb}[3]{\begin{quote} \begin{singlespace} \smaller \og {\itshape  #3} \fg \nolinebreak
\cite[#1]{#2} \end{singlespace} \end{quote}}

\newcommand{\kotc}[3]{\footnote{\begin{quote} \begin{singlespace} \smaller  \og {\itshape  #3} \fg \nolinebreak
\cite[#1]{#2} \end{singlespace} \end{quote}}}
```

- **Kota** combines **\enquote** and **\cite**,
- **Kotb** combines **\quote** and **\cite**
- **Kotc** combines **\footnote**, **\quote**, and **\cite**

It will be much easier and faster to write. Now in my document, I'm writing :

```
Comme le disait ce grand Broudic, \kota{200}{BROUDIC1995}{Bonjour les amis !}. Il avait tellement raison !\kotc{133}{BROUDIC1995}{Bonjour bonjour bonjour.}

\kotb{165}{BROUDIC1995}{Bonjour bonjour bonjour}
```

I have edited my initial question.

*Edited adding \nolinebreak to have the \cite informations on the same line as the quoted text.*